# Java desktop application with google calendar

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to build a desktop application with Java that shows the Google calendar on an interface, where a user can add and modify an event. To achieve this I am searching for the Google calendar API v3 but I can't really understand the examples provided. Can anyone give me some directions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you give us a link to the examples and tell us where you're getting stuck and why?

Comment: Here is the link to the one that I am looking right now. [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents) I am stuck where there is the line `Event recurringEvent = service.events().insert("primary", event).execute();` java cant recognise the keyword `service`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the import commands in the Java part of [Set up a Client Library](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/setup).  As that page explains, download the .jar files mentioned there and include them in your build path.

Comment: I downloaded both of them. but it seems that the two libraries contains the same code. I also managed to run the application from command line and also import it to Eclipse as specified by the API